# how to expand flagged enum

Tags: c#

I have a key combination like this

```
Keys key=Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D ...
```

I don't know how to expand key variable to separated Keys values. Maybe like this

```
foreach(Keys k in key)
{
   MessageBox.Show(k.ToString());
}
```

this seems stupid to me. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Keys key = Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D;

foreach (string s in key.ToString().Split(','))
{
    Keys k = (Keys) Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), s.Trim());

    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

See the definition of keys. All values act as normal, mutually-exclusive values, except the following:

```
//     The bitmask to extract a key code from a key value.
KeyCode = 65535,
//     The SHIFT modifier key.
Shift = 65536,
//     The CTRL modifier key.
Control = 131072,
//     The ALT modifier key.
Alt = 262144,
```

So all you need to check is the alt, control and shift. To get the non-shifted key, use

```
Keys value = key & Keys.KeyCode
```

To find out if shift, alt or control is pressed

```
bool altValue = key & Keys.Alt
bool controlValue = key & Keys.Control
bool shiftValue = key & Keys.Shift
```

And that's it

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's an int-based enum with component values 1, 2, 4... 2^n you could use:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DecomposeEnum<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    int intValue = (int)(object) value;
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 32 && intValue >> bit != 0; bit++)
    {
        int candidate = 1 << bit;
        if ((candidate & intValue) != 0)
        {
            yield return (T) (object) candidate;
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty grim in terms of boxing and unboxing, but it *mostly* works. Why mostly? Well, let's try this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Keys keys = Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D;
    foreach (Keys key in DecomposeEnum(keys))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
MButton
64
Shift
Control
```

This is because "D" isn't represented by a single bit, but a combination of bits.

The above code will work for "pure" flags types (which is why I'm leaving it here) but you may want to look elsewhere if you specifically want to use Keys.

Comment: Do you have a similar solution for going in the other direction? I.e. composition of an `IEnumerable<TEnum>` to a `TEnum`?

Comment: @gt: You could convert each value to an `int`, OR them together, then cast the result back to `T`.

Answer (score 2):

The flagged enums are just good old bit fields, so you have to use bit operations to see which values were set, e.g.:

```
foreach(Key i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
{
    if(key & i !=0)
        MessageBox.Show(i);
}
```

Comment: This is not good for a Keys enumeration since they are not bit fields except three values; all values until 65535 are normal enum values, so most keys will cause many message boxes here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach(int keyValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
    {
        if(k & keyValue != 0)
           Console.WriteLine(((Key)keyValue).ToString() + " is pressed");
    }
```

Comment: That will yield some extra values if the enum defines some convience combinations, e.g. "Default" or "AllValues".

Comment: @Jon if this is the case, it is possible to filter unwanted values by checking that Math.Log(keyValue)/Math.Log(2) is integer and not 0. (ie keyValue is power of 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1;
while (key > 0) {
    if ((key & (Keys)i) > 0)
        DoSomething();
    i <<= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keys enum has the [Flags] attribute so keys.ToString() already outputs "Control, Shift, D" without you having to do all that stuff.